createInertiaApp "undefined" is not valid JSON
I am creating separate Laravel and React projects using Inertia and Vite.
I am having a problem with the React project in the main.jsx file in the createInertiaApp function ("undefined" is not valid JSON).
I am sure that the Laravel response is working fine and I am getting the result for getting all users.
Laravel:
UsersController:
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return Inertia::render('Users', [
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }

React:
main.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import './App.css'; // Adjust the path as necessary

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
      console.log('Props:', props);
        createRoot(el).render(<App {...props} />);
    },
});

// Optional: Add progress bar
InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });

vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8000', // Adjust this if your Laravel server runs on a different port
        },
    },
});

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sift & Pick</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"></div> <!-- This is the root element for React -->
<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script> <!-- Adjust path as necessary -->
</body>

</html>

when I request the http://localhost:5173/users or http://localhost:5173/
I got a blank page and in the console I am getting: "undefined" is not valid JSON
I tried to make a console log in the createInertiaApp function but there is no results in the console.
